# how to label sentiment polarity in big text file?

Tags: python, nltk, tweets

Need some help with it! Sorry if it's sound stupid.
I am new to python and want to try [this](https://gist.github.com/1266556) example....

but labeling was made manually which is hard work if I have two .txt files(pos and neg) each with 1000 tweets.

Using example above how can I use it with text files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you need to figure out a way of reading text file into a Python object.

Considering you have two text files that contain positive and negative samples (`pos.txt` and `neg.txt`) with one tweet per line:

```
train_samples = {}

with file('pos.txt', 'rt') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        train_samples[line] = 'pos'
```

Repeat the above loop for negative tweets and you are done populating your `train_samples`.

Comment: I'd go with `1` and `-1` instead of `'pos'` and `'neg'`, just to make things a little easier

Comment: Maybe so, but that wouldn't be according to the example he gave.

Comment: I'm getting an `invalid syntax` error on the line `train_samples[line]: 'pos'`.

Comment: Sorry typo: should have been `train_samples[line] = 'pos'`!

Answer (score 0):

You should look for the genfromtxt function from the numpy package : http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.io.genfromtxt.html

It return a matrix, given the right parameters (delimiters, newline char, ... )